# Equation for all points in an area

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Definitely there is an equation for a line that can be generalized as

$$y = mx + b$$

However, I seem to find it difficult to find an equation describing all points in an area even for a simple shape such as circle. The closest I can think of is

$$x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$$

However, it's not an equation and I am not really satisfied with that. Is there something I don't know about functions of area?

Comment: If you have a shape that has non-zero area, for a given $x=a$ you will have multiple values of $y$ (just draw a line $x=a$). Thus, such function does not exist. You can also consider a shape as infinite number of line segments.

Comment: If simple and easy to understand and use inequalities are not to your liking, then enjoy hassling with space filling curves or functions.

Comment: equations tend to describe curves, not areas. for example a circle is actually a curve, but we tend to refer to a circle as the area inside that curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... there are ways to describe regions in terms of functions, and some of those functions are the so-called [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). And trust me, $x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$ is so, so much more intuitive (it's a result which illustrate an application of [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)) to work that defining this region in terms of a space-filling curve would be senseless. But, yeah, you could define $f(x,y) = \operatorname{sgn}(x^2+y^2-r^2)$ and then the circle as the set of points $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that $$f(x,y) = 0 \lor f(x,y) = -1.$$ But, as mentioned, that'd be less intuitive, probably harder to work and... just *equivalent*.

Comment: Is your last expression a function? or a condition? does the algorithmic unit in a cpu know `V` without any conditions?

Comment: “$\lor$” is the symbol in formal logic for “or”. So the last equations are $f(x,y) = 0$ or $f(x,y)=-1$

Comment: Oh, I see. The sgn() function is a bit new to me, does that mean that when the points lie inside the circle it will give -1 and when outside it will give 0?

Comment: The $\operatorname{sgn}$ function gives you the sign of a real number (actually, you can define it for more general “numbers”, but it’s not pertinent). For example $\operatorname{sgn}(-10) = -1, \operatorname{sgn}(7) = 1, \operatorname{sgn}(0) = 0$.

Comment: The case $\operatorname{sgn}(f(x,y)) = 0$ means that $f(x,y) = 0$, and the latter means that $f(x,y)<0$. So both equations are equivalent to $f(x,y) \leq 0$ which is $x^2+y^2 - r^2 \iff x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$. The point in all of this: describing the region as an inequality makes it not only more intuitive but also easier to handle.

Comment: I like that function, you were right though that its much easier to understand but inequality is a bit harder to vectorize.

Comment: You can parametrize it, tho. What I mean: this region can be described as the image of an injective function, for instance, $\sigma(\rho, \theta) = \rho(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ parametrizes the circle in the domain $[0, r[\times [0, 2\pi[$. So it’s easier to “vectorize”; but you usually can’t do this nicely using one function/equation.